# How to install sql server using configuration file?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, installation

How do I install SQL Server using a configuration file?

I have started, but after two steps it will stop and I have to click then it will move to the next step.

Please explain a step by step installation.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you attempting this with?

Comment: I highlighted the text in your question, right click google search and got this:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239405.aspx. Exactly which step in this did you fail at?

Comment: sql server 2012

Answer (score 0):

Insert the SQL Server installation media. From the root folder, 
double-click Setup.exe. To install from a network share, locate the root folder on the share, and then double-click Setup.exe. Follow the wizard through to the Ready to Install page.

check this it can help you out [Check the link for detail](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/dd239405(v=sql.110).aspx)

I have tried but not get success.

Comment: Can you please paste the steps whih you have performed.Actually link doesn't help me.

Comment: you still didn't found the solution..?